# Сборка Maven проекта

Tags: java, maven

Проект разбит на 3 модуля:

Корневой xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.java.art</groupId>
   <artifactId>airline</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <modules>
      <module>web</module>
      <module>services</module>
      <module>dao</module>
   </modules>

</project>
```

Проект представляет собой web-приложение. Как производится сборка проекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания артефактов используйте

```
mvn package
```

Для помещения артефактов в локальный репозиторий

```
mvn install
```

Для помещения артефактов в удаленный репозиторий

```
mvn deploy
```

Comment: Можно об этом где-нибудь почитать? Как производится создание и сборка многомодульных Maven проектов

Comment: да. на сайте maven.